# How to filter a list by the first letter of the list in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to filter a list with the first the first character. so far the search/filter works but it selects the item(s) that contain the character at at any position

HTML code

```
<input class="form-control" id="search-box" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for... " required="required"/>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <select class="form-control bg-light rounded-0 text-capitalize" id="search-filter" name="search-filter">
              <option value="listitem">All</option>
              <option value="name">Name</option>
              <option value="address">Address</option>
              <option value="email">Email</option>
              <option value="status">Status</option>
            </select>
          </div>
```

here is my JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-box").on("keyup", function() {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      var filter = $('#search-filter').val().toLowerCase();
      if(filter == "listitem") {
        $(".listitem").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      } else {
        $(".td-"+filter).filter(function() {
          $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      }
    });
    $('#search-filter').on("change",function(){
      var value = $("#search-box").val().toLowerCase();
      var filter = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      if(filter == "listitem") {
        $(".listitem").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      } else {
        $(".td-"+filter).filter(function() {
          $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      }
    });
     $(".tbl-btn").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).parent().parent().find('td:not(:first-child)').toggleClass('active');
       $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
     });
  });
```

Comment: [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: or `indexOf() === 0`